# How can I add an object to a NSMutableArray using a delegate?

Tags: class, delegates, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an object to an NSMutableArray taskArray. The object is an instance of taskClass called emptyTask.  When I create emptyTask and try to add it to myDelegate, I get following error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TaskClass copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c63f10

```
myDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
myDelegate.taskArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
TaskClass* emptyTask = [[TaskClass alloc]init];
emptyTask = [emptyTask starterTaskClass];
[myDelegate.taskArray addObject:emptyTask];
```

I can replace emptyTask with an NSString and it adds to myDelegate.
I can also add emptyTask to a locally created NSMutableArray and it works.
So it seems it has something to do with my class to myDelegate.
I have #import "TaskClass" in all of my header files.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is trying to copy your delegate somewhere down the line, either directly or (more likely) using it as the key in a dictionary. You have a couple options

- Figure out where and change it to not copy/use a dictionary; or
- Implement `-[TaskClass copyWithZone:]`; as long as you're doing that you may as well declare yourself to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.